# R: Enable autocompletion in custom class

Tags: r, autocomplete

I have created a new class, and I would like to enable R's autocompletion.

An example could be:

```
# Define class
setClass("customList",
     representation("list")
)

# Make example
tmp <- new("customList",
           list(
               test='a',
               b=1:3
           )        
)
```

Which result in:

```
tmp
# An object of class "customList"
# [[1]]
# [1] 'a'
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2 3
```

This custom list does have the names and named arguments can be used

```
names(tmp)
[1] "a" "b"
tmp$test
[1] 'a'
```

Now I would like to somehow enable the autocompletion, so I can simply type

```
tmp$t <TAB>
```

and get

```
tmp$test
```

How does one do that?

In advance - thanks!

Comment: Thanks for asking that question. 
In the command line R has autocompletion. But it would be preferable if the solution also worked with RStudio.

Answer (score 2):

As a general solution there is a generic function in R called `.DollarNames` which controls the auto-completions you get when pressing `<tab>` after the dollar sign on your custom class object.

As an example here is a function that would make it so that only the first name of your customList class is autocompleted:

```
.DollarNames.customList <- function(x, pattern="") {
  grep(pattern, names(x), value=TRUE)[1]
}

tmp$<tab>
tmp$test
```

Of course you would want to return all the results in a real case scenario. So the `[1]` at the end should be removed.

Answer (score -1):

Just install latest v0.99.660  [Rstudio](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) and autocomplete as described in your question should work without an issue.

**UPDATE:**

Here's example for GRanges class:

```
library(GenomicRanges)

gr1 <- GRanges(seqnames=Rle(c("ch1", "chMT"), c(2, 4)),ranges=IRanges(16:21, 20),strand=rep(c("+", "-", "*"), 2))
```

Then you can type :

```
gr1@
```

And Rstudio will show the auto-complete pop-up as shown on next picture:

[image]

You can continue using **@** to go deeper in the class structure and select specific elements.

Comment: That did solve the problem for the custom class I put in as an example - but it does not generalize to for example GRanges (where one can access the meta columns in a R command line).

Comment: what is **GRanges** ?

Comment: Sorry - the full name is GenomicRanges and it is one of the Bioconductor main object types.
http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html

Comment: @Kristoffer,  has my post helped you?

Comment: unfortunately not - the solution does not generalize (does not hold for amongst others GRange).